# How ThreaPool reuses threads if thread itself can not be restarted?

Tags: multithreading, threadpool, python-multithreading

I am trying to understand the concept behind the threadpool. Based on my understanding, a thread can not be restarted once completed. One will have to create a new thread in order to execute a new task. If that is the right understanding, does ThreadPool executor recreates new thread for every task that is added?

Comment: while(true){waitForWork();doWork();}

Answer (score 1):

> One will have to create a new thread in order to execute a new task

No. Task are an abstraction of a logical work to perform. It can be typically a function reference/pointer with an ordered list of well-defined parameters (to give to the function). Multiple tasks can be assigned to a given thread. A thread pool is usually a set of threads waiting for new incoming tasks to be executed.
As a result, threads of a given thread-pool are created once.

Comment: Simply put, a thread pool does not stop or terminate its threads unless either the entire thread pool is shutting down or the thread pool decides it has too many threads. Otherwise, the threads run code that continues to accept assignments and perform them.

Comment: Thanks, @DavidSchwartz but If ThreaPoolExecutor creates a thread to execute a task and once that task is completed, doesn't the thread exit and a new thread has to be created?

Comment: @Jérôme Richard Thank you. I understood your point of giving multiple tasks to a thread but once the thread execution completes for a given task, is it capable of restarting/retaking a new work?

Comment: @KetanPatel 'once the thread execution completes for a given task, is it capable of restarting/retaking a new work?' sure, why not?

Comment: @KetanPatel The threads only finishes when all the tasks (typically submitted by a master thread) has been completed (by the worker threads in the thread pool) and the master threads submitting the tasks implicitly signals the workers that there will be no more work to complete anymore. In Python, this last operation happens tipically when the `with` section capturing the thread-pool object ends.